# Dynamically changing comboBox list, Only one panel is working

Tags: java, combobox, actionlistener, jcombobox

I am creating an expense report program for school and we can only use what is in the book so I have had to compromise on things. My calendar picker I made from comboBoxes. I want the days options to change dynamically with the month that has been chosen. For some reason it only works on the returnPanel and not departPanel.

Yes there are many unnecessary things imported but I just keep a list since things keep changing.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.List;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class TestWindow extends JFrame {

    private JPanel departPanel;
    private JPanel returnPanel;
    private JComboBox monthsBox;
    private JComboBox daysBox;
    private JComboBox yearsBox;
    private JComboBox departTimeBox;
    private JComboBox returnTimeBox;
    private JLabel calendarLabel;

    private String[] months = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul",
                                 "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };
    private String[] days = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8",
                                "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16",
                                "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24",
                                "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31"};
    private String[] years = {"2015"};
    private String[] time = {"1:00AM", "2:00AM", "3:00AM", "4:00AM", "5:00AM",
                                "6:00AM", "7:00AM", "8:00AM", "9:00AM", "10:00AM",
                                "11:00AM", "12:00PM", "1:00PM", "2:00PM", "3:00PM",
                                "4:00PM", "5:00PM", "6:00PM", "7:00PM", "8:00PM",
                                "9:00PM", "10:00PM", "11:00PM", "12:00AM"};

    public TestWindow() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));

        buildDepartPanel();
        buildReturnPanel();
        add(departPanel);
        add(returnPanel);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void buildDepartPanel() {

        departPanel = new JPanel();
        monthsBox = new JComboBox(months);
        daysBox = new JComboBox(days);
        yearsBox = new JComboBox(years);
        departTimeBox = new JComboBox(time);

        JLabel departLabel = new JLabel ("Departure");

        departPanel.add(departLabel);
        departPanel.add(monthsBox);
        departPanel.add(daysBox);
        departPanel.add(yearsBox);
        departPanel.add(departTimeBox);

        monthsBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                if(monthsBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Jan")
                    || monthsBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Mar")
                     || monthsBox.getSelectedItem().equals("May")
                      || monthsBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Jul")
                       || monthsBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Aug")
                        || monthsBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Oct")
                         || monthsBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Dec")) {

                    int items = daysBox.getItemCount();
                    if(items == 29) {
                        daysBox.addItem("30");
                        daysBox.addItem("31");
                    } else if(items == 30) {
                        daysBox.addItem("31");
                    }

                } else if(monthsBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Apr")
                            || monthsBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Jun")
                             || monthsBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Sept")
                              || monthsBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Nov")) {

                    int items = daysBox.getItemCount();
                    if(items == 29) {
                        daysBox.addItem("30");
                    } else if(items == 31) {
                        daysBox.removeItemAt(30);
                    }

                } else if(monthsBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Feb")) {

                    int items = daysBox.getItemCount();
                    if(items == 31) {
                        daysBox.removeItemAt(30);
                        daysBox.removeItemAt(29);
                    } else if(items == 30) {
                        daysBox.removeItemAt(29);
                    }                   
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void buildReturnPanel() {

        returnPanel = new JPanel();
        monthsBox = new JComboBox(months);
        daysBox = new JComboBox(days);
        yearsBox = new JComboBox(years);
        returnTimeBox = new JComboBox(time);

        JLabel returnLabel = new JLabel ("Return");

        returnPanel.add(returnLabel);
        returnPanel.add(monthsBox);
        returnPanel.add(daysBox);
        returnPanel.add(yearsBox);
        returnPanel.add(returnTimeBox);

        monthsBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                if(monthsBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Jan")
                    || monthsBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Mar")
                     || monthsBox.getSelectedItem().equals("May")
                      || monthsBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Jul")
                       || monthsBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Aug")
                        || monthsBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Oct")
                         || monthsBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Dec")) {

                    int items = daysBox.getItemCount();
                    if(items == 29) {
                        daysBox.addItem("30");
                        daysBox.addItem("31");
                    } else if(items == 30) {
                        daysBox.addItem("31");
                    }

                } else if(monthsBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Apr")
                            || monthsBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Jun")
                             || monthsBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Sept")
                              || monthsBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Nov")) {

                    int items = daysBox.getItemCount();
                    if(items == 29) {
                        daysBox.addItem("30");
                    } else if(items == 31) {
                        daysBox.removeItemAt(30);
                    }

                } else if(monthsBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Feb")) {

                    int items = daysBox.getItemCount();
                    if(items == 31) {
                        daysBox.removeItemAt(30);
                        daysBox.removeItemAt(29);
                    } else if(items == 30) {
                        daysBox.removeItemAt(29);
                    }                   
                }
            }
        });

    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestWindow();
    }
}t
```

Answer (score 0):

The instance variable's (monthsBox, daysBox, etc...) that maintain references to the JComboBox's get created when you call buildDepartPanel, and again in buildReturnPanel. When the ActionListener is called, it uses the current reference (which in this context is the last one created - in buildReturnPanel). Can be fixed in a variety of ways, for instance create instance variables for these objects that represent both the depart and return panels. Given the code duplication that occurs between the two build methods, you might be better off creating a general method or class to consolidate the duplicated code. For instance:

```
public class DatePanel extend JPanel{
    //instance variables here
    public DatePanel(){
         //construct UI
    }
}
```

Then just create instances of this class and add them to your UI

```
DatePanel returnPanel = new DatePanel();
add(returnPanel);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes it is basically all duplicated code, I had planned on creating a class and then instantiating them. I just whipped this up quickly an was not sure why it was not working. It is obvious now. I'll work on it

Answer (score 0):

Your combo boxes are fields, which means they're at the object level. There's only one of each per TestWindow instance. When you call your buildReturnPanel() method, it's overwriting the value you already set in the buildDepartPanel() method, so when your action listeners are called they only see the return combo boxes.

Ideally, because your depart and return panels are the same, I'd suggest having a separate class for the set of UI items and instantiating it twice. I don't know if that's possible for your assignment or not. If you can't, then you can declare the combo boxes as final inside the methods:

```
final JComboBox monthsBox = new JComboBox(months);
...
```

The use of `final` will let the anonymous ActionListener class see the variable.